# how to achieve subdomain url rewrite using modrewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect website user to www.mywebsite/users.php?user=xyz when the user types http://xyz.mywebsite.com into the address bar where http://xyz.mywebsite.com is virtual and doesnt exist.

I am a beginner and doesnt know much about url rewriting. Tried to search google and stack overflow but didnt got the solution.

I started with this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).mobilehealthnig.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mywebsite.com/users.php?subdomain=%1
</IfModule>
```

also tried this but none of these are working for me

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mywebsite.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+).mywebsite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /users.php?subdoamin=%1
```

Comment: I suggest you simply read the excellent manual of mod_rewrite. It comes with a good explanation of all options, good examples and hints: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: And if you cannot figure out how to solve your problem after that, please post what you have tried so far (your code) and what is the specific problem you cannot solve.

Comment: @arkascha - I tried that already and here is what I have started with.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based on your additional input I suggest this setup:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.mywebsite\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mywebsite.com/users.php?subdomain=%1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

If that does not work (I take that from your comment), you have to check where the actual problem is:

- does rewriting work at all?
- does this rule do anything atall? what?
- is that rule ignored? why?

What absolutely makes most sense in such cases is to turn on rewrite logging to see and understand what is actually happening inside the rewrite engine. Please take a look at the two commands `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` inside the manual mentioned. Enable a log level of maybe 7 and look what is logged when you make a single request. It should give you an idea of where to look for the cause of the problem.

Comment: Can you please give me some example about how to use RewriteLog?

Comment: Example for the use of rewrite logging? May I suggest that you simply read the fine manual? It is excellent! Comes with good explanations for all options and commands and even clear examples! Why do people never read the manuals? It helps! http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html